# Are some trophies still bugged?

Tags: ps4, dying-light

There are/were following bugged trophies in Dying Light on the PS4

bronze:

- This is Harraaaaan! (Kill 100 enemies by kicking them off the rooftops/cliffs)
- Homo Homini Lupus Est (Save 15 survivors from Rais's men)

silver:

- Now It's Safe (Capture all Safe Zones)
- Trespassing (Complete all Quarantine Zones)
- It's All In the Writing (Find all text collectibles)

gold:

- The Whole Story (Finish all side quests)

---

Are those trophies still bugged in the latest patch?

Answer (score 2):

The latest patch that I've received was from February 12th, and I can confirm that at least one of those trophies is still glitched. Homo Homini Lupus Est has not been earned for me, although the Personal Statistics part of the menus tells me I've saved 18.

I have seen on other sources that Polyamory is also not unlocking for some people.

Comment: Ah! Just today I earned Homo Homini Lupus Est! It seems that Duran is right! I'm up to about 22 survivors saved in the statistics, but I just earned the trophy today. Seems you have to save people 15 times, not 15 people.

Answer (score 1):

Just save more people, because sometimes you save 2 and this counts just for 1! 
But in the Statistics looks like you save 2!

For Example: 
Save 8 times 1 and 4 Times 2 People 
--> Statistics Count 16 People.
--> Trophy Counts 12 People!

Thats a little bug but should be no problem!

Harder is the Side Quest Trophy, i still didn't get it! *-.-

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out but that's not an answer to my question, take it and post it as comment under my question or Kaizerwolfs answer please, thank you